# Email Notification from MS Project using VB macro

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-project

I would like an email notification from MS Project whenever a predecessor task is marked as completed. I would like it to email a predesignated resource and the project manager. I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by "send an email" you mean send an email through Outlook, then you can use this method. MS Project does not have task-level events but you can use the Project_Change event; you just need to loop through all tasks to see which ones need emails to be sent.

In this example, I stored the recipient's email address in the hyperlink field and I use the Flag1 field to indicate whether or not an email has already been sent. The email is left open for the user to review before clicking the send button; leaving it open also avoids the pop-up message where the user must approve programmatic access to Outlook.

```
Private Sub Project_Change(ByVal pj As Project)

Dim tsk As Task
Dim succ As Task
Dim ol As Outlook.Application
Dim mail As Outlook.MailItem

For Each tsk In ActiveProject.Tasks
    If tsk.PercentComplete = 100 And Not tsk.Flag1 Then
        If ol Is Nothing Then
            Set ol = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
        End If
        For Each succ In tsk.SuccessorTasks
            Set mail = ol.CreateItem(olMailItem)
            mail.To = tsk.Hyperlink
            mail.Subject = "A precedessor task has been completed"
            mail.Body = "Task " & tsk.ID & " which is a predecessor to your task " & succ.ID & " has completed."
            mail.Display
        Next succ
        tsk.Flag1 = True
    End If
    Next tsk

End Sub
```

Note: Be sure to add the MS Outlook object library reference.